# Bad conversion in Request params to object binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, datatables

working with jQuery DataTables + C# Asp.NET MVC 5 and Server Side feature, I build a representative class for DataTable ajax request (guided by [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)):

```
public class Query
{
    public List<QueryColumn> columns { get; set; }
    public List<QueryOrder> order { get; set; }
    public QuerySearch search { get; set; }

    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string dtid { get; set; }
}

public class QuerySearch
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}

public class QueryColumn
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public QuerySearch search { get; set; }
}

public class QueryOrder
{
    public enum Order
    {
        asc, desc
    }
    public int column{ get; set; }
    public Order dir { get; set; }
}
```

All this, respecting lower case as JSON attribute mapping requires. Also, in javascript DataTable initialization, I added all columns definition:

```
$("#mydatatable").DataTable({
serverSide: true,
processing: true,
info: true,
order: [[0, 'asc']],
ajax: {
    data: function (d) {
        // Extra params to request
        d.dtid = iddt;
    },
    url: '@Url.Action("Home", "ListEntities")',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    dataSrc : "entities"
}
lengthMenu: [[15, 50, 100], [15, 50, 100]],
pageLength : 15,
columns: [
    { name: "Entidad", data: "NombreEntidad", title: "Entidad" },
    { name: "Numero", data: "Numero", title: "Numero" },
    { name: "Fecha", data: "Fecha", title: "Fecha" },
    { name: "Estado", data: "Estado", title: "Estado" },
    { name: "ConsignadoA", data: "ConsignadoA", title: "Consignado a:" },
    { name: "Identificador", data: "Id", "searchable": false, "sortable": false, title: "Acciones" }
]
});
```

At this point everythings looks right, but debugging the request it fill the class Query, except the columns and order sublist, as figures show:

[image: DevTool on Firefox]
[image: Debugging]

Any idea why this happens?